# How to check if the request I've sent was rejected?

Tags: android, quickblox, quickblox-android

How to check if the add friend request I've sent has been rejected in QuickBlox?

When I send request to someone he's added to my roster as (Type.none), but when he rejects my request he should be removed from my roster!

Comment: Can you post a link to the 'add friend' request documentation? (I would be surprised if there is an endpoint for this, since you might not want another user to know if you have denied their request.)

Answer (score 0):

**Add/Remove users**

To add users to the contact list just use the method below:

```
int userID = 56;

if (chatRoster.contains(userID)) {
    try {
        chatRoster.subscribe(userID);
    } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {

    }
} else {
    try {
        chatRoster.createEntry(userID, null);
    } catch (XMPPException e) {

    } catch (SmackException.NotLoggedInException e) {

    } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {

    } catch (SmackException.NoResponseException e) {

    }
}
```

now you need to implement this `QBSubscriptionListener`

This user will receive the request to be added to the contact list

```
 @Override
public void subscriptionRequested(int userId) {

}
```

for more info follow its [doc link](https://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample#Add.2FRemove_users)

Comment: Yes I've already done that. 
But I want something like a listener or some way to detect if the person I've sent the request has rejected my friend request so I can remove him from my roster.

Comment: did you check it -https://docsdev.quickblox.com/android/Chat/Contact_list.html#Contact_list

Comment: Yes, but I couldn't find something like that.
When the recipient rejects the request, the "entriesUpdated" method is invoked but I don't know how can I check sent requests!